# The example of the coroutine from documentation does not work

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I started to learn *coroutine* and have tried run the code from example [structured-concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#structured-concurrency). But I got another result. If set `delay(1000L)` ***"Hellow, "***  only was printed and `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`. But if I set `delay(100L)` I get ***"Hello,World!"***. Why `launch{}` block not launch?

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { // launch a new coroutine in the scope of runBlocking
        delay(100L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello,")
}
```

[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvfkS.png)
  [screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BitCk.png)

Comment: What version of kotlin and coroutines are you using?

Comment: this sample works on [playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org)

Comment: @EricMartori implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.1'  and   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.21'

Comment: Googling around for this error code comes up with some windows/driver-related problems. I'd suggest to update your Java version to the latest 1.8.0 patch version and to update your windows video drivers (they usually are causing some weird problems).

Comment: @RomanElizarov it didn't help. I found out that programm work correctly if I work in another account in my Windows 10. I deleted config folder for Intellij, but it didn't resolve problem. Perhaps some other system configurations affect the execution. And I mainly work in Android Studio, everything is fine there. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I disabled the program "Punto switcher" and now all work correctly.